# How do I create a boxplot in Stata comparing variables from two datasets?

Tags: stata, boxplot

I have two datasets, each with eight columns representing eight chemicals. The datasets are of different populations and cannot be combined. How can I generate a box plot in Stata comparing the eight chemicals between the two datasets?

Comment: As hinted by @noobie, you will need to `append` and create a variable recording which population is which. http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0062 contains relevant technique.

Comment: Another option is to open each dataset, make the box plot, save it, and then  `graph combine` the two plots. This will make it harder to make some types of comparisons, but may suffice for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stata cannot handle multiple datasets at the same time into the RAM. It's a great software but this limitation is one of its biggest weaknesses.

You must combine your two datasets if you want to compare your chemical variables across the two datasets.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Added a vote. In essence, this is right. Specifically, the advice is surely to `append` datasets.

Comment: As you can `append` and `merge` this "limitation" is less than it seems.

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to do this with R and Excel.

In R, get summary statistics for both datasets via the following code:

```
boxplot(mydata1, plot=F)
boxplot(mydata2, plot=F)
```

Then copy the summary statistics data into Excel and follow instructions from the following website: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/boxandwhisker-charts-for-excel.html

It's a bit confusing, but I ended up with great plots.[image]

Comment: These really don't look like box plots at all. The capped intervals don't align with the boxes. (Also, the text labels are barely legible.)

Comment: Also, it's your question and your right to post and accept an answer, but the answer isn't an answer to the original question, as you don't give a Stata solution. (If you don't care what software you use, in turn that's your right, but that's a different issue.)